# How can I install a tar.gz package in the terminal?

Tags: package-management

How do I install a `tar.gz` package in Ubuntu 13.10 in the terminal? Must I use `apt-get`? I have tried to use the `.deb` package commands, but that doesn't work. Ubuntu software center will not open the package.

Comment: What about this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file

Answer (score 0):

If the application is a compiled application this is typically how you do it

```
tar xzvf TARFILE.tar.gz
cd (New Folder Name)
./configure
make 
make install
```